# Cmd + Tab showing different windows from a single app?

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is there a way for Cmd+Tab to display all of the instances/windows of an app?

An excellent example is here: [image]

Notice how it shows the available instances of that application? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think it's happening. Since OS X has a feature called "Mission Control", little people make windows manager app for OS X. Use Mission Control under "Application Window" mode, find it under System Preferences.

Comment: I'm very familiar with Mission Control. It just doesn't do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) does exactly that, with a ton of configuration options. It can also use the default **Cmd - Tab** shortcut.

Comment: Functionally it's nearly perfect. The only issue is it has to be activated in each Desktop before it can read the windows in that desktop - but apparently that isn't Witch's fault. Thanks!

Comment: I later found [DockView](http://kapeli.com/dockview) which looks great, but I have yet to try it.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about seeing the window thumbnails, <kbd>⌘ - `</kbd> (the key above the Tab key) switches between open instances of an app.

Comment: At first glance this appears to be limited to instances that are in the same space/desktop. Is that correct?

Comment: Seems it's not working on OS X Yosemite :(

Comment: @artnikpro I use it in Yosemite. Have you customized your shortcuts? See [this image](https://imgur.com/gallery/bIzSE7m/new).

Comment: @shabdar I have the same settings as you. I tried to use the combination on a few opened windows of Chrome and Finder. Not working for me :(

Comment: If the window has an active text field, then ⌘ - ` ends up typing a  ` inside the text field instead of switching windows.